# C++ check If a hexadecimal consists of ABCDEF1 OR 0

Tags: c++, hex

I have written a program  below that converts a string to an int and then converts the decimal number to hexadecimal. I'm struggling to check if the hexadecimal consists only of these characters A, B, C, D, E, F, 1, 0. If so set a flag to true or false.

```
#include<iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>


string solution(string &S){

    int n = stoi(S);
    int answer;

    cout << "stoi(\"" << S << "\") is "
            << n << '\n';

    //decToHexa(myint);
    // char array to store hexadecimal number
    string hexaDeciNum[100];

    // counter for hexadecimal number array
    int i = 0;
    while(n!=0)
    {
        // temporary variable to store remainder
        int temp  = 0;

        // storing remainder in temp variable.
        temp = n % 16;

        // check if temp < 10
        if(temp < 10)
        {
            hexaDeciNum[i] = temp + 48;
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            hexaDeciNum[i] = temp + 55;
            i++;
        }

        n = n/16;
    }

    // printing hexadecimal number array in reverse order
    for(int j=i-1; j>=0; j--){
        cout << hexaDeciNum[j] << "\n";


    return "";
}
```

int main() {

```
string word = "300";

cout << solution(word);

return 0;
```

}

Comment: why do you want to check if your hexadecimal consists of only "ABCDEF 1 or 0"? Do you mean "1-0 or A-F", i.e. all valid hex digits? And if so, why check at all? If your conversion is implemented correctly, it can't ever not be. Making sure your conversion works is preferable to catching failures.

Comment: No need of checking that, since you divided `n` by 16 its guaranteed that you will always get a remainder of below 16 (i.e. 0 - 15). As you already know, remainders from 10 - 15 will be replaced by the letters A - F. So you don't need to check that, just make sure that your code works correctly while converting.

Answer (score 1):

OK, it is not the *exact* answer to what you are asking for, but it is a valuable *alternative approach* for the entire problem of conversion:

```
char letter(unsigned int digit)
{
    return "0123456789abcdefg"[digit];
    // alternatively upper case letters, if you prefer...
}
```

Now you don't have to differenciate... You can even use this approach for inverse conversion:

```
int digit(char letter)
{
    int d = -1; // invalid letter...
    char const* letters = "0123456789abcdefABCDEF"; 
    char* l = strchr(letters, letter);
    if(l)
    {
       d = l - letters;
       if(d >= 16)
           d -= 6;
    }
    // alternatively upper case letters, if you prefer...
}
```

Another advantage: This works even on these strange character sets where digits and letters are not necessarily grouped into ranges (e. g. [EBCDIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC)).

Comment: Just in passing: digits are always grouped into ranges. That is, `ch - '0'` always returns the value that a digit character in `ch` represents.

Comment: @PeteBecker Haha, extra for you, I'll invent up a character set where this is not the case...  Now seriously: I proposed this approach mainly for its simplicity. Suppose doing range checking and just having fix additions/subtractions might be more efficient at least on some platforms (especially when converting character to digit), so we might keep this in mind for the case my variant, during profiling, turns out to be a bottle neck...

Comment: @Aconcagua -- invent all you like; your character set cannot be used in C or C++ because it doesn't satisfy the requirements that those languages impose.

Comment: @PeteBecker Got me - didn't know that this was specified for digits 0-9. Remains the solace that I at least could rearrange the letters...